# wxGrid destructor Triggers Breakpoint on

Tags: wxwidgets, wxgrid

I'm new to wxWidgets, although I've been able to get an application up and running fairly smoothly up until this point. For the main window, I'm using a wxGrid inside a wxPanel. Everything runs fine until I close the program.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

The grid is a member of a class derived from wxPanel:

```
class FormDataView
        : public wxPanel
    {

public:
    FormDataView(wxWindow* parent);
    virtual ~FormDataView();

private:
        wxGrid* grid_;
    }
```

And created in the constructor. The data for the grid comes from another thread, so I create a custom event for actually writing the data.

```
wxDEFINE_EVENT(FORMDATAVIEW_UPDATE, wxThreadEvent);


FormDataView::FormDataView(wxWindow* parent)
        :   wxPanel(parent,wxID_ANY )
    {

    wxBoxSizer* mbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    grid_ = new wxGrid(this, wxID_ANY );
    grid_->CreateGrid(0, 0);


    mbox->Add(grid_,wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());


    Bind(FORMDATAVIEW_UPDATE, &FormDataView::onDataUpdate, this);

    }


///
/// This function is called by a child thread when data is received.
///
void
FormDataView::onDataReceived(IFORMATTERBASE_PFONDATARECEIVED_ARGS)
    {
    newHeaders_ = headers;
    newData_ = data;

    wxThreadEvent* evt = new wxThreadEvent(FORMDATAVIEW_UPDATE);
    evt->SetString("Yo.");
    wxQueueEvent(this, evt);

    }


///
/// Called by the event loop. This function puts the data
/// into the grid.
///
void 
FormDataView::onDataUpdate(wxThreadEvent& evt)
    {
    FormatterStringList& headers = newHeaders_;
    FormatterStringList& data = newData_;

    if (grid_->GetNumberRows() <= 0)
        {

        wxGridCellAttr* attr = new wxGridCellAttr();
        attr->SetReadOnly(true);
        attr->SetAlignment(wxALIGN_CENTRE, wxALIGN_CENTRE);
        for (size_t i = 0; i<headers.size(); ++i)
            {

            if (grid_->GetNumberCols() <= 0)
                grid_->InsertCols();
            else
                grid_->AppendCols();


            grid_->SetColLabelValue(i, headers[i].data());
            grid_->SetColAttr(i, attr);
            }
        }


    // suspend redrawing while we add data.
    grid_->BeginBatch();

    // insert a new row at the top of the table
    grid_->InsertRows(
        0, // position
        1, // number of rows to insert
        true); // update labels (not current used)


    for (size_t i = 0; i<headers.size(); ++i)
        {

        if (data.size() < i)
            {
            grid_->SetCellValue(0, i, "");
            }
        else
            {
            grid_->SetCellValue(0, i, data[i].data());
            }
        }

    // resume redrawing.
    grid_->EndBatch();
    }
```

Everything runs fine, but when I close, I get the following message. I've indicated the line upon which the breakpoint occurs. Is there some short of sequence for clearing data out of the grid I'm supposed to follow?

```
wxGrid::CellSpan
wxGrid::GetCellSize( int row, int col, int *num_rows, int *num_cols ) const
{
    wxGridCellAttr *attr = GetCellAttr(row, col);
    attr->GetSize( num_rows, num_cols );
    attr->DecRef();

>>>>>>>    if ( *num_rows == 1 && *num_cols == 1 )
        return CellSpan_None; // just a normal cell

    if ( *num_rows < 0 || *num_cols < 0 )
        return CellSpan_Inside; // covered by a multi-span cell

    // this cell spans multiple cells to its right/bottom
    return CellSpan_Main;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code you show, but this just means that the bug is in the code you do not show, which makes it difficult, if not impossible, to find it. At least look at why does the code crash, maybe the stack trace shows some hints... (also check in which thread it happens).

Comment: Actually, the problem was in the code shown; I figured it out this morning. And I'm a bit embarrassed. Edited code with corrections.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with where I was creating the column attribute. I was re-using the same column attribute instance for every column, but each column needs to have its own instance.

BEFORE:

```
if (grid_->GetNumberRows() <= 0)
    {

    ///
    /// NO! The columns will share the same cell attribute
    /// instance.
    ///
    wxGridCellAttr* attr = new wxGridCellAttr();
    attr->SetReadOnly(true);
    attr->SetAlignment(wxALIGN_CENTRE, wxALIGN_CENTRE);
    for (size_t i = 0; i<headers.size(); ++i)
        {

        if (grid_->GetNumberCols() <= 0)
            grid_->InsertCols();
        else
            grid_->AppendCols();


        grid_->SetColLabelValue(i, headers[i].data());
        grid_->SetColAttr(i, attr);
        }
    }
```

CORRECT:

```
if (grid_->GetNumberRows() <= 0)
    {
    for (size_t i = 0; i<headers.size(); ++i)
        {

        if (grid_->GetNumberCols() <= 0)
            grid_->InsertCols();
        else
            grid_->AppendCols();


        grid_->SetColLabelValue(i, headers[i].data());

        ///
        /// Each column will have its own cell attribute.
        /// Supposedly, the column will take ownership of this
        /// instance.
        ///
        wxGridCellAttr* attr = new wxGridCellAttr();
        attr->SetReadOnly(true);
        attr->SetAlignment(wxALIGN_CENTRE, wxALIGN_CENTRE);
        grid_->SetColAttr(i, attr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is indeed a mistake but it *cannot* explain the crash. You have another bug in your code somewhere.

Comment: It was definitely the cause of the crash. I tested and was able to reproduce the problem in a new project that had nothing but the code above.

Comment: This seems downright impossible but I'm willing to be proved wrong -- please make the minimal changes reproducing the problem to the [grid sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/tree/WX_3_0_2/samples/grid) included in wxWidgets and open a [Trac](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/) ticket.